# Comparing attributes/property of API response with local stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a method in my `model` which returns me the below `object` which i convert into json.

```
got: "{\"@type\":\"accountResource\",\"createdAt\":\"2014-08-07T14:31:58\",\"createdBy\":2,\"updatedAt\":\"2014-08-07T14:31:58\",\"updatedBy\":2,\"accountid\":2055,\"name\":\"Test\",\"description\":\"Something about Test\",\"disabled\":false}"
```

How can i compare the `attributes` alone with my `stub`.

Below is my spec

```
it "can create an account" do    
    acc = FactoryGirl.create(:account, name: "Test", 
                         description: "Something about Test");
    create_account = Account.create(account: acc)
    expect(create_account.to_json).to eq(what)     
end
```

I need to compare with my local `json` that the json returned from `API` has the same `attributes` that i have in local. I don't want to check for values, only for `attributes` whether they are same or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any requests. I think, what you want will be like this:

```
it "can create an account" do
  attrs = Factory.attributes_for(:account)
  account = Factory.create(:account, attrs) # instead of this you should do you request
  expect(JSON.parse(account.to_json)).to eq(attrs)
end
```

In case of the request expectation will be next:

```
expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(attrs)
```

If you want to skip some attributes like created_at, you need a custom matcher like this:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :eq_attributes do |sample|
  match do |actual|
    sample.reject { |k, _| %w(id updated_at created_at).include? k }.all? { |k, v| actual[k] == v }
  end
end
```

It skips `id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`. With it expectation will be next:

```
expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq_attributes(attrs)
```

Comment: expect(JSON.parse(response.body)) to eq(attrs) will it not check both key and value?

Comment: Just take key arrays and compare. For matcher `expect(actual.keys).to match_array(sample.keys)`

Comment: [There](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers) you can find more matchers.